# Find all values of a parameter for which some quadrics have 4 common points of intersection

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric, quadrics

$2|xy-3y-4x+12| = a^2+2a-z-30$ and $3a^2-a-z-32=0$ and $z-x^2-y^2+6x+8y=0$

What I've got: $3a^2-a-32=x^2+y^2-6x-8y$ so $(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 = 3a^2-a-7$ and this is circle

$2|xy-3y-4x+12|=-2a^2+3a+2$. Assume value inside module > 0:
$2xy-6y-8x+24=-2a^2+3a+2$, so $(-2a^2+3a+2)/(2(x-3)) + 4 = y$ - it is hyperbola(reflected relatively y-axis). And I stuck.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title: it is not a good idea to put equations in a title.

Answer (score 1):

the term between the absolut value signs can written as $$(x-3)(y-4)$$ now you can do case work

Comment: It's not that easy. I can't solve it anyway

Comment: Ok, I solve it, thanks